# Is $f(x)=10$ a periodic function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am not getting satisficatory explanation for this. Clearly $f(x+T) = f(x)$ for all values of $T$.

If we assume it is periodic, does this mean period =  $0$?

Comment: It just means that it is periodic for any value of $T$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function

Comment: We do not normally consider $0$ to be a possible period of a periodic function; if we did, then every function would be periodic.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000468/are-there-periodic-functions-without-a-smallest-period/1000470#1000470

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What it means is that any number is a period. There is no "minimum" period though.

Comment: thank you ! that clears up the confusion :) so this looks like a degenerate case of periodic functions where the function satisfies the definition but the graph doesn't look periodic(example : y^2=x^2 is a conic by definition but the graph is just a pair of intersecting lines)

Comment: $$\text{Harry Potter shouts: The minimum period is $h$ tends to zero!}\\
\text{Dumbledore retorts: ... or }\frac{1}{\infty} $$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every constant function is periodic, and when you look at the definition of a periodic function with period T (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function)) then it's easy to see that a constant is periodic with any positive number as period. So $f(x)=10$ is $n-$ periodic for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: No need to restrict $n$ to $\Bbb N$; it is periodic for every $n\in \Bbb R$, in fact.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: thanks! that wiki link says period has to be a positive constant. however allowing negative/complex periods should be okay i guess concept wise - its just a matter of how we  define after all ;)