# Are there periodic functions without a smallest period?

Tags: analysis, periodic-functions

The Wikipedia page for periodic functions states that the smallest positive period $P$ of a function is called the fundamental period of the function (if it exists). I was intrigued by the condition that the function actually has a smallest period, so my question is, what properties of a function would cause it to be periodic but not have a smallest period?

Comment: If you don't require the function to be continuous, every subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ is the period group of a periodic function.

Comment: Perhaps more interesting: are there periodic continuous non-constant functions with no smallest period?

Comment: No, there doens't exist periodic continuous non-constant functions with no smallest period. Actually, it doesn't end there: there doesn't exist periodic "somewhere continous" non-constant functions with no smallest period. (That is, if you want a periodic function to have no smallest period, the you must make it either constant or nowhere continuous). There is a proof below.

Comment: @Przemysław: I don't understand the motivation for the bounty. "This question has not received enough attention"?

Comment: @Rahul Alas, I can only choose one of the possibilities, not my own choice. And this would be "It is a Christmas gift".

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I still don't understand your motivation. Can you please explain it?

Comment: I'm just going to leave a link to a related [question](https://www.quora.com/Apart-from-constants-and-the-Dirichlet-function-are-there-any-other-periodic-functions-without-the-prime-period/answer/Alexey-Godin-2?ch=10&share=8877d7ad&srid=5D37D) on Quora.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

For a nontrivial example, consider the Dirichlet function, which has $$\delta(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if $x$ is rational}\\1 & \text{ if $x$ is irrational}\end{cases}$$

Then $\delta(x)$ is periodic with period $r$ for every rational number $r$.

Comment: I guess this is a consequence of the fact that there are irrationals(in fact infinitely many) between any 2 rationals?

Comment: @Cruncher Actually no, rather it's because $\alpha$ is irrational if and only if $\alpha+r$ is, for any rational $r$.

Comment: I noticed that this construction is constant, if you restrict the domain to only the rational numbers. I then wondered if there exist any construction, which is non-constant even if the domain is only the rational numbers. Turns out there does. One could define $f(x)$ to be $0$ if $x$ can be written with a finite number of decimals, and $1$ if $x$ requires infinitely many (repeating) decimals. This would be periodic with period $10^{-n}$ for any $n$.

Comment: Yes, you can do a similar thing by letting $f(x) = 1$ for rationals of the form $2^{-n}$ and $f(x) = 0$ for rational numbers not of that form.

Comment: As other comments have pointed out, if $S$ is any additively-closed subset of $\Bbb R$ (that is, $a+b\in S$ whenever $a\in S$ and $b\in S$) then the characteristic function of $S$ has no smallest period. In my example in this post, $S=\Bbb Q$; in your example it is the set of terminating fractions.

Comment: @MJD Your $f$ in the comment does not seem to be periodic, and in the next comment, you probably left "dense" out?

Comment: Thanks.   meant rationals of the form $k2^{-n}$.

Answer (score 87):

Yes, for example constant function.

Comment: I cannot believe I overlooked that.

Comment: @AlexMiller  But there are also non-constant functions with such property.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke This appears to be the only continuous one, so it's certainly note-worthy! Although, I'm almost tempted to say that the period is 0 in this case.

Comment: @Cruncher But the fundamental period is smallest **positive** period and every positive number is a period.

Comment: #cruncher We don't consider zero to be a period because if we did, every function would be periodic, since $f(x+0) = f(x)$.

Comment: IMO This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Kartik no, it should be a comment or an edit to the original question. Clearly the reply is "I mean besides constant" so it adds little value.

Answer (score 38):

In fact, a *continuous* function of a real variable having arbitrarily small periods is necessarily a constant. Indeed, the set of periods is then a dense additive subgroup of the real line, and the function is constantly equal to its value at any point.

Comment: Would be nice if you included a proof of the first statement.

Comment: @Mehrdad Did you read the second sentence?

Comment: @Mehrdad Left as an exercise for the reader. It's quite trivial.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to suppose $f$ is globally continuous. You only have to suppose $f$ is continuous at at least one point for it to be constant.

Comment: @fonini Would be nice if you included a proof of the second statement

Comment: @Mehrdad Check out my comment XD

Comment: @BCLC it's in my answer to this question :) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1003808/113664

Answer (score 15):

You can show that if a periodic function is continuous at at least one point, and doesn't have a minimum period, then it is constant.

In other words: in order for a function to have arbitrarily small periods, it must be either constant or everywhere discontinuous.

The reasoning is simple: if $f$ doesn't have a smallest period, then the image of $f$ must be the same in every open interval. Therefore, no matter how small is $\varepsilon$, the oscillation of $f$ in any $(a, a+\varepsilon) $ (defined as $\sup f - \inf f$ restricted to that interval) is going to be the same as the global oscillation. Since the oscillation is constant as $\varepsilon\to 0$, and we know that the oscillation should converge to $0$ if we want $f$ to be continuous at $a$, we reach the conclusion that $f$ is nowhere continuous (allowing that $f$ is constant in the case that this global constant oscillation is $0$).

It is easy to obtain "examples" of constant functions. As MJD's answer says, an example of a non-constant function with arbitrarily small periods is the indicator function of the rationals ($1$ at the rationals and $0$ at the irrationals). As noted by Hagen von Eitzen in MJD's post, this function doesn't accept a smallest period because a real number $x$ is rational if and only if $x+r$ is also rational for any rational $r$ (hence any rational number is a period of this function).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a large family of nontrivial examples with an uncountable set of periods. Select a Hamel basis $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $f_\alpha: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}$ be the extraction of the coefficient of some fixed $x_\alpha$. Then any rational multiple of any element of the Hamel basis other than $x_\alpha$ itself is a period of $f_\alpha$.