# Everywhere discontinuous and periodical function should has no minimum positive period?

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Let $f$ be an everywhere discontinuous and periodical function, can we justify that $f$ has no minimum positive period? If yes, provide the proof; if no, give an example.

Take the Dirichlet funcition, we see that there exists an everywhere discontinuous and periodical function, who has no minimum positive period. And this let me ask the question above...

Notice that the question is an arbitrary everywhere discontinuous and periodical function! I have no idea, since I just know Dirichlet funcition as an everywhere discontinuous function....

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1000475/568973
Nice answer and nice comments below the answer

Comment: No, of course not. Take $f(x)=\{x\} d(\{x\})$ where $d$ is the Dirichlet function and $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio the $f$ is continuous at $x=0$? $f(x)=\{x\}, x\in \Bbb Q$, and $f(x)=0, x\not\in \Bbb Q$.

Comment: @xldd No, it isn't continuous in $0$, and yes to the other two observations.